# ViewModel valid on httpget - invalid when form posted back - can I post back a different model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ViewModel filled with a place object and some other data by a controller.

In the view bound to this ViewModel the user selects an item from a dropdownlist and presses submit - which is caught by an action method with [httppost].

At this stage, all I am interested in is the value the user selected in the dropdownlist - not any values from the ViewModel - whose only purpose was to populate the page (aside from the single DropDownList value).

However - as the place object did not populate form fields by design (I don't need those values back - or to even display most of them) - the model posted back is now invalid - due to some fields being [Required] and an error is raised.

I want to bind a complex ViewModel to the view when the [httpget] creates the page. Then, when the user selects a value and presses submit - I no longer need that ViewModel - or to validate it.

Essentially I want to get a different model in [httppost] to the one I use in [httpget].

Is this possible or advisable - or does it break how model binding is supposed to work? Would making a specific ViewModel with no validation be required to avoid errors when un-bound model items come back empty?

(I'm not able to find any guidance on this point on Google).

Comment: Why are you applying a `[Required]` attribute to a view model property if its not required (a view model represents only what is need in the view its being used in)?

Comment: Place is a Model inside a ViewModel. Place has [Required] properties. Should I be putting DataAnnotations inside a Model? Should I be placing a Model inside a ViewModel?

Comment: A view model should not contain data models (for this very reason). You view model should contain properties for each property of 'Place' that you want in the view (and no validation attributes applied to them)

Comment: Would you implement a hard rule that no validation attributes be placed in Models - but only in ViewModels?

Comment: No, validation should be applied to data models. Its just the view models represent what is need for the view, and they should not contain properties which are data models

Comment: @StephenMuecke Regarding the other comment you posted, if you have the single string/int type as the httppost action method param. It wont fire the validation(Just verified it). So if OP is not worried about validating a single field, he can go that route as well.Having view specific view model would be the right way though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to bind a complex ViewModel to the view when the [httpget]
>   creates the page. Then, when the user selects a value and presses
>   submit - I no longer need that ViewModel - or to validate it

If you are using the view model for only displaying something in the view. Why you even have the Required tags. you should create and use a simple view model which has properties needed for the view. Have the [Required] attribute only in the property you really need validation for.

```
public class SimplyInfoVm
{
  public string Name { set;get;}  // to Display some name

  [Required]
  public int SelectedStateId { set;get;}

  public List<SelectListItem> States { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your GET and and view use this. You can use the same view model for your HttpPost action parameter as well. When form is submitted, Model validator will try to validate only `SelectedStateId`

In short, **Your view model's should be specific for your view. Create view models as the view needs them.**

Comment: Reason for [Required] attribute - Place is a Model inside a ViewModel. Place has [Required] properties. Should I be putting DataAnnotations inside a Model? Should I be placing a Model inside a ViewModel? –

Comment: No. Do not try to mix entity model and view models (specially for form submission, just display purpose is fine (while i still do not do that). You should create  a new view model specifically for your specific view.

Comment: Hold on your first answer was actually really interesting - binding that single value to the httppost - can you post that in another answer please?

Comment: I do also take your point about ViewModels - in this case making a separate ViewModel does make sense.

Comment: @niico That might not work if you want to validate that single field. Best solution is to use the view specific view model.

Comment: ok thanks - but you are saying you can have a sub-object or property of the model that is bound to the view as a parameter on the action method - you don't have to pass the full object as a parameter? I didn't realise this - that is good to know even if not applicable here.